# How do you launch a custom develop blockchain in truffle?

Tags: truffle

I am using truffle 5.0.30 and I want to create a development blockchain where I can run and test my contracts. This is the `truffle-config.js` that I am using:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    mynet: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8547,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
      gas: 8700000, 
      gasLimit: 8900000
    }
  },

  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
       //version: "0.6.4",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
       settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true,
          runs: 100
        },
        //evmVersion: "byzantium"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

When I start the network with the command `truffle develop --network mynet` I get this output:

```
Warning: possible unsupported (undocumented in help) command line option: --network
Connected to existing Truffle Develop session at http://127.0.0.1:9545/
truffle(mynet)>
```

Which indicates that it has created a blockchain with default values instead of using the ones specified in the `mynet` configuration. How can I force truffle to use the settings in `mynet`?

Comment: `develop` is not a valid command-line option, perhaps you wanted to run `truffle console --network mynet` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create your own network you should use ganache, ganache-cli or test-rpc. Those are local blockchain test networks you can configure.

After setting up and running your network you should add the network config to your `truffle-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost", // your if
      port: 8545, // Your port
      network_id: "5777" //
      // ...other config
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can interact with your network via `truffle console --network development` or migrate contracts via `truffle migrate --network development`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own simulated blockchain by running Ganache in a separate process. In the truffle-config.js you can change the specifications of the development network and then just run `truffle test` it will use development by default. In your case it would probably look like this

```js
development: {
  host: '127.0.0.1', // This might be different for you
  port: 8545, // This might be different for you
  network_id: YOUR_GANACHE_NETWORK_ID,
  gas: 8700000, 
  gasLimit: 8900000
}
```

or you could probably set the gasLimit when spinning up ganache like so:
`ganache-cli --gasLimit: 8900000`